# Where are the giant lizards in this chapter of Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, encounter-tables, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

*Hoard of the Dragon Queen* indicates that there are giant lizards

> in "Greenest in Flames" (p. 7): "the streets of Greenest are overrun by forces consisting of, cultists and acolytes accompanied by monstrous allies: kobolds with ambush drakes and giant lizards." In the next paragraph, it reads "Roll 1d8 on the Episode 1 Encounters table to determine each encounter."

The table in question contains:

> kobolds, ambush drakes, cultists, guards, acolytes, and townsfolk,

but no **giant lizards**. I skimmed the chapter a few times and couldn't find anything more on it.

So, why are they listed here if they don't show up in the encounter table?

Comment: Do not answer in comments, answer in answers.

Answer (score 7):

### Out of universe explanation

As several people alluded to in the comments, this adventure was written under pressure as they were still developing the rules. The MM, in particular, was far from finalized; the [adventure errata](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/errata-may-2016) (worth checking out if you have an older printing) include a lot of changes to monsters, especially **guards** which were [apparently considerably stronger](http://www.enworld.org/forum/content.php?1909-HOARD-OF-THE-DRAGON-QUEEN-Author-Steve-Winter-Clarifies-A-Few-Points!) during development than the CR 1/8 version that made it to publication. So a lot of the details are sketchy, and changes may not be cross-referenced and reflected everywhere they should be.

### In universe explanation

The text says the city is under attack by a variety of forces, not all of whom are directly faced by our heroes. Frulam Mondath and the lizards are in the background of this episode, not participants in any of the action we see.